# Go template Passing data from one to another

Tags: go, go-templates

I have to Go Template file. I need to pass some value from one template to another. IE

Template A have two variable with .Name and .Type. The values are passing from go code with ctx.Data. Template A references Template B with

```
{{ template "B" . }}
```

But in Template B. .Name and .Type are not having the same name. I can not change Template B s variable references because Tempalte B is used directly with those variable.
Template B looks like this.

```
Username : {{ .UserName }}
Type : {{ .UserType }}
```

Now my question is how can i change the .Name in template A to .UserName?

```
{{ tempalte "B" .Name as .UserName }}
```

is there something like this????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with current version of Go's text/template or html/template package.

You would need to append "Name" and "UserName" to `ctx.Data` on the Go side for them to be accessible with those exact names in template B.

You may want to look into pongo2, a Django-like template for Go (https://github.com/flosch/pongo2)

Your specific use case in pongo2 is documented here: https://github.com/flosch/pongo2/blob/master/template_tests/includes.tpl